# Mocking the sort method from Collections

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a code that I want to unit test. The code uses `Collections.sort` method providing it with our own sweet comparator something like :

```
List<Something> something = somethingService.doSomething(someParameter);
Collections.sort(something, somethingComparator);
```

Now while testing the function I am mocking the `somethingService` and stubbing the `doSomething` method like :

```
List<Something> mockList = Mockito.mock(List.class); 
Mockito.when(somethingService.doSomething(anyInt())).thenReturn(mockList);
```

and I am mocking the Collections as :

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Collections.class);
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Collections.class, "sort", anyListOf(Something.class), anyOf(Comparator.class));
```

But it is giving me :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced argument matcher detected
You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
```

Now I do know that if we are using argument matchers in any param of a function we need to provide matchers to all the params. But here is it possible to do the same and if not then what is the existing workaround?

Comment: @Community : Please help :)

Comment: This is strange. I get the same problem. But this [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22991435/1594933) works

Comment: @Gontard : I have also tried most of the workarounds available on the web but in vain. I even tried spying but then again they give a different problem. Right now all I can think of he providing fakes instead of mocks and making the unit test case run.

Comment: Yes you could avoid to mock the list and stub the sort method.

Comment: Why do you need to mock Collections anyway?  What exactly are you testing?

Comment: I wanted to test my flow as well as the comparator in the single flow. If my list is getting sorted out properly using my comparator for a series of test cases I would not be required to test the comparator as a unit again.

Comment: Could you use java 8 ?

Comment: No :( but what feature does it provide?\

Comment: There is [sort method on list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-). This method is not static so the usage of powermock could be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You are using PowerMock to mock a **system class** from the JDK, design wise it's really, really **nasty**. Seriously one should really think over his [motivation to use Powermock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/Motivation) as the author himself is.

Powermock cannot really mock directly static methods from system class, you have to create *wrappers* around the system calls, as documented in the [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockSystem).

I would strongly advises you to extract some sorting strategy, that you could mock with just Mockito.

Comment: The wiki entry show how to mock `URLEncoder`. So why it doesn't work with `Collections` ?

Comment: I think you need to wrap the call. However without the complete code we cannot help you diagnose much more than that.