# Powermockito: intercept all static methods

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

This code mocks a static void method in a class and overrides its behavior. (Taken from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22981048/1345655))

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Resource.class})
public class MockingTest{

    @Test
    public void shouldMockVoidStaticMethod() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.spy(Resource.class);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Resource.class, "readResources", Mockito.any(String.class));

        //no exception heeeeere!
        Resource.readResources("whatever");

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
        Resource.readResources("whatever");
    }
}

class Resource {
    public static void readResources(String someArgument) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("meh!");
    }
    public static void read(String someArgument) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("meh!");
    }
}
```

How can I intercept all method calls instead of individually specifying the methods?

It tried `PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Resource.class)` and `PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Resource.class, Matchers.anything())` but these do not work.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(Resource.class, Matchers.anything())
```

Doesn't work because `Matchers.anything()` creates a matcher for `Object` and the above `when()` is trying to find methods based on the type. Try passing instead `Matchers.any(String.class)`. This will only work for static methods with the same parameter lists. Not sure if there's a way to make a more generic override.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock ALL static methods of a class, I think you can use `PowerMockito.mockStatic(..)` instead of `PowerMockito.spy(..)`:

```
   @Test
   public void shouldMockVoidStaticMethod() throws Exception {
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(Resource.class);

      //no exception heeeeere!
      Resource.readResources("whatever");

      PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
      Resource.readResources("whatever");
   }
```

Hope it helps you.