# UnfinishedStubbingException when mock static method with Mockito.mockStatic

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I got this exception when mock the `LocalDate.now()` static method with `Mockito.mockStatic()`.

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException:
> Unfinished stubbing detected here:
> at utils.PowerMockTest.test(PowerMockTest.java:18)
>
> E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
> Examples of correct stubbing:
> when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
> when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
> doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
> Hints:
>
> 1. missing thenReturn()
> 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
> 3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction is
>    completed

code is

```
public class MockStaticTest {
    @Test
    void test(){
        LocalDate today=LocalDate.of(2020,11,20);
        try (MockedStatic mocked = mockStatic(LocalDate.class)) {
            mocked.when(LocalDate::now).thenReturn(LocalDate.of(2020,11,10));
            Assertions.assertEquals(today,LocalDate.now());
            mocked.verify(atLeastOnce(),LocalDate::now);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm a bit confused by the exception message because I certainly added `thenReturn` statement.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77569633/3679900) I was getting this exception since I had forgotten to add `@PrepareForTest({ClassToMock.class})` annotation on my test-class

Answer (score 6):

You need to instantiate the return object outside of your try block.

The issue is that you are mocking the `LocalDate` class, and then trying to use that same class within the mocked `try` block;

```
mocked.when(LocalDate::now).thenReturn(LocalDate.of(2020,11,10));
```

@sankv answer works because it instantiates the returned `LocalDate` prior to the static block.

Comment: I met the same problem and solved. but why it is happened??

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
private LocalDate expectedReturn = LocalDate.of(2020, 11, 20);

    @Test
    void test() {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.of(2020, 11, 20);
        try (MockedStatic<LocalDate> mocked = Mockito.mockStatic(LocalDate.class)) {
            mocked.when(LocalDate::now).thenReturn(expectedReturn);
            Assertions.assertEquals(today, LocalDate.now());
            mocked.verify(Mockito.atLeastOnce(), LocalDate::now);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works,but I wander why my statement is illegal.

Answer (score -1):

did you try
mocked.when(LocalDate.now()).thenReturn(LocalDate.of(2020,11,10));
?

Comment: Please don't write answers in a way that makes them look like questions.
There are systems in place to check for Not An Answer (NAA) posts.
This answer was falsely picked up by one of them. Please consider editing it to look more like an answer.